# How do I update the data in my firebase real-time database with the existing data along side a randomly generated id

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm sending data from a form to my database. As I've understood correctly, using .push() creates a unique ID where my data is appended to and uploaded. I need to now get that same data and then add a new ID entry. But I can't reference the data since its stored under the unique ID created by the .push() method.

```
exports.addUser = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => { //Adds data from the form to the database
  cors(req, res, async () => {
    // Grab the message body parameter.
    const entry = req.body;
    // Push the new message into the Realtime Database using the Firebase Admin SDK.
    const snapshot = await admin.database().ref('entries/users/').push(entry);

    console.log('my new shiny id is ' + snapshot.key());
    // Redirect with 303 SEE OTHER to the URL of the pushed object in the Firebase console.
    res.redirect(303, snapshot.ref.toString());
  })
});

//Function to generate a random ID and update into the entry from the form on the database.
exports.generateID = functions.database.ref('entries/users/').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
  const original = snapshot.val();
  console.log(context);
  console.log(snapshot.key());
  const dev = '0eeb94ca-3426-46ca-964d-a9bdd7d00ef0';
  var random = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
  const code = uuidv5('user-' + random, dev);
  return snapshot.ref.update({
    userID: code
  });
})
```

Here is an image of the data structure in my real-time database.
[image: database structure]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you meant to use a wildcard in your function in order to capture that ID (and also trigger on only that new node):

```
functions.database.ref('entries/users/{id}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
```

Now you can use `context.params.id` to get that ID, and write more easily under that new node.

Comment: Could you please stretch out your last point? "Now you can use context.params.id to get that ID, and write more easily under that new node."

Answer (score 0):

All I needed to do was pass in a parameter into my ref url.

```
exports.addUser = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => { //Adds data from the form to the database
  cors(req, res, async () => {
    // Grab the message body parameter.
    const entry = req.body;
    // Push the new message into the Realtime Database using the Firebase Admin SDK.
    const snapshot = await admin.database().ref('entries/users/').push(entry);

    console.log('my new shiny id is ' + snapshot.key());
    // Redirect with 303 SEE OTHER to the URL of the pushed object in the Firebase console.
    res.redirect(303, snapshot.ref.toString());
  })
});

//Function to generate a random ID and update into the entry from the form on the database.
exports.generateID = functions.database.ref('entries/users/{id}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
  const dev = '0eeb94ca-3426-46ca-964d-a9bdd7d00ef0';
  var random = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
  const code = uuidv5('user-' + random, dev);
  return snapshot.ref.update({
    userID: code
  });
})
```

The `{id}` will stand as a parameter for the ID created by the `.push()` method. The function will update the data entry with the generated ID.